# variable de un struct

Tags: c, struct

Estoy creando un pequeño programa para hacer pedidos "una especie de tienda". He creado un struct, y cuando quiero generar una variable del mismo, me da algún tipo de error que desconozco "el programa no sigue ejecutándose". Dejo un poco del código, y tengo alguna anotación por si sirve de guía. Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct lista_pedidos{
    char nombre_farmaco[50][21];
    
};


char nuevo_pedido(){
    int Ref_Pacientes;
    int numero_envios[1000];
    int dia_envio;
    int mes_envio;
    int ano_envio;
    int peso_farmaco[3000];
    int unidades_farmaco;
    char respuesta_farmaco;
    char respuesta_pedido;
    int fecha;
    
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("Nuevo pedido:\n");
        printf("\tNumero de envios? "); scanf("%d",&numero_envios);
        printf("\tDia del envio? "); scanf("%d",&dia_envio);
        printf("\tMes del envio? "); scanf("%d",&mes_envio);
        printf("\tA%co del envio? ",164); scanf("%d",&ano_envio);
        fecha = dia_envio + mes_envio + ano_envio;
        struct lista_pedidos c[fecha];
        
        do{ //por algun motivo, el programa se para y este "do" no se ejecuta
            printf("\tNombre farmaco (Entre 1 y 20 caracteres)? "); scanf("%s",&c[fecha].nombre_farmaco);
            printf("%s",c[fecha].nombre_farmaco); //impresion de prueba
            printf("\tOtro farmaco (S/N)? "); scanf("%s",&respuesta_farmaco);
                
        }while(respuesta_farmaco=='s' || respuesta_farmaco=='S');
        printf("Otro pedido (S/N)? "); scanf("%s",&respuesta_pedido);   
    }while(respuesta_pedido=='s' || respuesta_pedido=='S');
    
} 


int main(){ //funcion principal
    nuevo_pedido();
}
```

Comment: La variable `respuesta_pedido` es de tipo `char` y en la función *scanf* usas el especificador `%s` cuando debería ser: `%c` (esto hace que *scanf* lea únicamente un caracter). Y por cierto, esto es síntoma de un comportamiento indefinido, puesto en mi máquina tu código si funciona y en la tuya no :)

Comment: Recomendaría habilitar las advertencias de compilador y prestar atención a ellas. [Mira esto](https://ideone.com/S12myC).

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea:

```
struct lista_pedidos c[fecha];
```

Es errónea de dos maneras.

### Formaciones de tamaño variable ([FtV](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla)).

En [c](/questions/tagged/c), las formaciones<sup>1</sup> declaradas en memoria automática<sup>2</sup> necesitan un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación; ese no es el caso de `fecha`, cuyo valor se conoce en tiempo de ejecución.

Cuando defines una formación usando como tamaño el valor de una variable, obtienes una Formación de tamaño Variable; las FtV no son C estándar y pueden no tener soporte o funcionar de manera errática, aún suponiendo que tu compilador de soporte a FtV tienes otro fallo...

### Tamaño de la memoria automática.

La cantidad de memoria automática de la que dispone un programa se limita mediante opciones de configuración y puede variar de un compilador a otro pero en general podría ser alrededor de 1Mb; suponiendo que tu compilador soporte FtV y suponiendo que las variables `dia_envio`, `mes_envio` y `ano_envio` son `26`, `11` y `2020` respectivamente, nos da que `fecha` tiene un valor de `2057`. Cada `lista_pedidos` tiene un tamaño de `1050` bytes, que multiplicado por el tamaño solicitado nos da `2159850` bytes, el doble de lo que soporta la memoria automática.

### Posible solución.

Cambia la FtV por memoria dinámica:

```
struct lista_pedidos *c = malloc(fecha * sizeof(struct lista_pedidos));
```

No olvides liberar la memoria al acabar.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

<sup>2</sup>Toda memoria que no sea dinámica, es decir la no se solicitada con `malloc`.

Comment: "las FtV no son C estándar" No exactamente. Son una parte de estándar desde 1999. Esta formación no es necesaria porque se usa un solo elemento de ella. Este código tiene suficientes otros errores. `scanf("%s",&c[fecha].nombre_farmaco);` , `scanf("%s",&respuesta_farmaco);`, `scanf("%d",&numero_envios);`.

Comment: @n.m.ןoṵɐdsǝᴉɯɐןƃǝɹɹɐ el estándar C99 soporta las FtV, pero a partir del estándar C11 dicho soporte pasa a ser opcional.

Comment: Correcto, pero la opcionalidad de las FtV no es el problema más grave de este código. Es el último que debería arreglarse.

Comment: Jamás dije que fuese el problema más grave Ô_ô

Comment: Si tu respuesta aborda un problema menor, es mejor mencionarlo.

Comment: Mi respuesta aborda el problema que menciona el autor de la pregunta en el primer párrafo: "*el programa no sigue ejecutándose*".

Comment: El código tiene suficientes casos de comportamiento indefinido tanto antes como después `struct lista_pedidos c[fecha];`. Esta declaración per se **no** es comportamiento indefinido. Cambiar esta declaración puede ocultar comportamiento indefinido en otros lugares, pero no es la correcta manera de solucionar problemas.

Comment: Jamás dije que esa declaración fuese comportamiento indefinido. ¿Por qué no hacemos una cosa?: Escribe una respuesta mejor que la mía y te voto positivo, creo que es más productivo que escribir en los comentarios sin aportar nada a la respuesta.

Comment: Esta pregunta requiere una respuesta complicada, puedo escribir solo repuestas simples, mi español no es muy bueno. Puedo intentarlo algún día.